# A property of polynomials with nonnegative coefficients and constant term 1.

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, contest-math

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with non negative integer coefficients and constant term 1, having $n$ real roots. Prove that $p(2) ≥ 3^n$

I'm actually getting the opposite result, $p(2) < 3^n$

Since it has only positive (or zero) coefficients, it must only have negative roots. If the roots are $-a_i$, $1≤i≤n$, then $p(x) = (x+a_1)(x+a_2).....(x+a_n)$ where $a_i ≠ a_j$ for $i ≠ j$

Then $p(2) =  (a_1 + 2)....(a_n + 2)$. The only way for $p(2) > 3^n$ is if each of the $a_i$ are $≥ 1$, but this is impossible, since $a_1a_2..a_n = 1$. Of course we can still have $p(2) = 3^n$, but then the appropriate result to prove would be $3^n ≥ p(2)$. Am I wrong?

Edit: I realize now that the statement 'the only way for $p(2) > 3^n$ is if each of the $a_i$ are $≥1$ is wrong. So the question is, how would I prove this(the original problem)

Comment: $x^2+3x+1$ is such a polynomial and $P(2) >3^2$.

Comment: @cosmo5 yes I realize that my proof was wrong and the original statement is probably correct. Can you help me prove that(the original statement)

Comment: I gave it a try using inequalities, but I wasn't able to bring binomial coeffs. Maybe somebody else can help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with non negative real coefficients and constant term $1$, having $n$ real roots.

As you said, the roots have to be negative as $P(x) > 0$ for all $x \ge 0$.

As such, we can write $P(x) = \prod_{k=1}^n (x+r_k)$ such that $r_k \ge 0$ for all $k$ and $r_1 \cdot r_2 \cdot r_3 \ldots r_n = 1$

We can plug $2$ into that expression to get:
$$
P(2) = \prod_{k=1}^n (2+r_k)
$$

Here, we can use the AM-GM inequality to proceed.
\begin{align*}
\frac{r_k + 1 + 1}3 &\ge \sqrt[3]{r_k \cdot 1 \cdot 1} \\
\implies 2 + r_k &\ge 3 \sqrt[3]{r_k} \\
\implies  \prod_{k=1}^n (2+r_k) &\ge 3^n \sqrt[3]{\prod_{k=1}^n r_k} \\
\implies P(2) &\ge 3^n
\end{align*}

Here, I split the $2$ into $1+1$ in order to get $3$ in the denominator.

In the end, we didn't need to use the fact that the coefficients of $P$ were integers so I don't know what's up with that.